# NodeJS + SocketIO large socket event management

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I have a million Dinosaur Users all logged in.

Dinosaurs want to see when other Dinosaurs update their profile in real time, so they are hooked into the NodeJS/Mongoose model as:

    `dinosaur.schema.post('save', function (doc) {
        socket.emit('dinosaur:save', doc);
    });`
where `socket` is the socket of the connected Dinosaur.

Dinosaurs are also going to see real time updates from several other things.  Maybe news, comments, etc etc.

So, my question, is there some instance where this emitting of events will grow large and impact performance?

On the client side, I'll have something like `socket.on('dinosaur:save', function(){})`... I destroy the listeners when not needed.  BUT, if I'm listening to every `dinosaur:save`, I could theoretically be processing that for a million saves a second (say if every dinosaur updated their profile in the same second).  It just seems like there's a better way to do that with large data sets.

I imagine there are several other events I may want to watch and I'm just wondering if there are some recommended methods for this kind of socket management.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm aware of rooms, but if I, for example, have a scrolling list of all nearby Dinosaurs in my area, I probably just want to hook into receiving all of the `dinosaur:save` events.  So I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in the future, here's the problem and my current solution.

We want real time updates.  If you're on someones profile page, and t hey update it, show that.  If you're viewing some catered result set, say, of user profiles, and any one of those users updates their profile, show that.  If you're on another page and some counter changes, say, of users near you, show that.  But, we aren't going to be on all these pages at the same time, so on the client side *i don't even want to know about the other changes if I'm not on those other pages*.  This is the problem that could cause me to be notified of *everything* which could cause bandwidth issues, and a whole bunch of unecessary socket usage.

So, the way I'm solving my problem is using [rooms](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#rooms).  I'm using rooms over namespaces because namespaces are generally used for two mutually disjoint applications accessing the same socket resource.  Rooms also just fit better with this application.

I've created a dynamic, on the fly room for every user profile page.  When a visitor opens a profile page have the client call `socket.emit("joinRoom", modelName + ":" + modelObj._id);` and on the server handle that with `socket.on('joinRoom', function(room) {
    socket.join(room);
});`.  This automatically creates the room if there isn't one yet.  And adds the user to it.  modelName could be whatever we want.  It's just a naming convention of how I split up the rooms.  You can call rooms anything.  BUT the important part is the `._id` at the end.  Using Mongoose, no two DB objects can have the same `._id`, so this guarantees unique rooms.

When the owner of this profile page updates their information we call on the server: 
`io.sockets.in('Dinosaur:' + doc._id).emit("Dinosaur:" + doc._id + ":updated", doc);` And receive that on the client side using 
`socket.on(modelName + ":" + modelObj._id + ":updated" , function(msg){
    // do something
})`

Viola, we have only sent this necessary information to the interested clients.

--
( A separate problem )  --
Using this approach, we can also deliver data pertaining to multiple users.  if we have a catered result list of user profiles, for each profile, we can add the current user into the rooms of all of those catered result profiles. (So they're in a room belonging to `_id` X, `_id` Y, `_id` Z, etc.
The current user would then be in multiple rooms, all reflecting the immediate updates of those users, and therefore the entire catered result list, for whatever list it may be (perhaps it is "Dinosaurs nearby").
Another approach to this, especially if the list is somewhat more static, is to have the socket re-deliver the result set every X seconds, using the same socket, and just the same initial room.

Answer (score 1):

Notifying a million of anything is a lot of packets and if the thing you're notifying occurs a lot, that's a lot of a lot and it's even more than a lot to try to show on screen.

The usual first things to consider are:

1. How real-time do these notifications really have to be?  Can you batch up 60 seconds or longer of notifications into one packet per user per notification period?
2. Does every user really have to see every single change from every other user.  You know there's absolutely no way that any user interface can present the state of a million other users.  So, I'd argue that every user doesn't have to know about the state of every other user.  Maybe if there's 1-50 other users, but not if there's a million.
3. Can you algorithmically determine which users state a given user might be interested in and only broadcast to them.  For example, can you keep them up to date only on other users that are geographically near them?
4. Can you have a user interface where the user tells you which other users they want to track so you only update those?  Or perhaps some combination of users they tell you about and users who are geograpnhically interesting to them.  The point is that you can't watch a million users anyway so you're going to have to invent a UI that shows a lot less than that anyway.
5. You can always have a UI that will fetch the state of other users upon demand if the client doesn't already have that state, so you don't have to keep the state for all million users in each client (since it can't possibly all be shown at once anyway).  If the user browses to see some things they don't already have, you just fetch it from the server via the socket or ajax call.
6. Oh, and at the scale you're talking about, you are probably going to need to have your user's connections spread out among several servers so you're going to have to handle that complexity too.

Comment: Maybe a good place to start the question is: if I emit an event on every 'dinosaur:save' is that even a problem?  Let's just say there are a million users, again.  If I want to update my dinosaur profile page and have that update propagate in real time to the users, how is that best achieved?  I would imagine from this answer, it's NOT best achieved by simply emitting a 'dinosaur:save' event with my new dinosaur information.  Any ideas?

Comment: @AugieGardner - Doesn't my answer already contain a number of ideas?  You batch changes, you only notify relevant users, you fetch info on some users on demand rather than broadcast realtime, etc...  I feel like you just glossed over the options I've already presented as if they somehow weren't relevant.  Do you get that keeping realtime info on 1,000,000 of anything in a browser is probably just wasteful and making your problem harder than it need be as no viewer can process that much info and if they want to search or browse, you can always fetch relevant info upon demand from the server.

Comment: I guess my problem is not so much with the theory, but with the application, I'm not sure that's very clear.
Lets say, for example, I have a Dinosaur who's interested in seeing Dinosaurs near him so theres a scrollable list of Dinosaurs near him on the home page.  Let's say we want to sync if Dinosaurs in this list change their location, and they may.  Could you give a concrete exampled approach to how this is solved from client to server if not with updates on every `dinosaur:save`?  Create a room for this scrolling list?  Or...? Feel free to modify answer with an example and I can accept

Comment: @AugieGardner - for large scale (millions of items moving around) that is a complicated problem to do efficiently.  Let's say you want a scrolling list in the client of all Dinosaurs that are within X distance of your location.  To keep that list up-to-date in each client, then everytime a dinosaur moves, you'd have to figure out who it's neighbors are and notify them of the new position and anyone who used to be a neighbor, but is no longer needs to get told they are no longer nearby (e.g. remove them from the list).  Doing these distance calculations across millions of users is complicated.

Comment: @AugieGardner - I haven't personally done that type of distance calculation, but I have seen algorithms written in articles for how to approach that type of problem more efficiently than calculating the distance from the one that moved to every single other dinosaur.  If that's specifically what you want help with, then I'd suggest you describe that specific problem in a new question and see if you can attract some folks who've done something like that before.  Right now your question looks more like a sockets about managing socket traffic.

Comment: Okay perhaps I was over complicating it.  What if I want to sync if they update a more trivial piece of information?  Like their name, or their status?  Lets say they like to update their statuses A LOT.  I'm just trying to understand how this whole "Only update for those you want" is played out.  And also, if it's necessary

Comment: @AugieGardner - Who you need to update in real-time with what information is a property of your application and what it's trying to do.  Not really something we can answer for you without fully understanding the objectives and priorities of your app.

Comment: Dinosaurs near you.  With updated bios and statuses.  I'm throwing that out there.  As a theoretical example.  So I can better understand the application of the theory you proposed